Image not loading in Android app using web view when reading from device Android studio
I've used web view from an html file in Android studio app. However, sometimes the app doesn't load the images properly. In the virtual device in android studio it always works perfectly, however in real devices it doesn't load images most of the times. Like here
(https://i.sstatic.net/r054nFkZ.jpg)
I've tried putting in cache and everything but it just won't get fixed.
Here's my code for the image reading part in my MainActivity.java:
// Load the HTML file

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");



        // Initialize file chooser result launcher

        fileChooserLauncher = registerForActivityResult(

                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),

                result -> {

                    // Handle result of file chooser

                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {

                        // If multiple files selected

                        if (result.getData().getClipData() != null) {

                            int count = result.getData().getClipData().getItemCount();

                            Uri[] resultUris = new Uri[count];

                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                                resultUris[i] = result.getData().getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                            }

                            filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultUris); // Pass result to WebView

                        }

                        // If single file selected

                        else if (result.getData().getData() != null) {

                            Uri[] resultUris = new Uri[]{result.getData().getData()};

                            filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(resultUris); // Pass result to WebView

                        }

                        else {

                            filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null); // No file selected

                        }

                    } else {

                        filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null); // Handle cancellation

                    }

                }

        );

    }


How about vitrual and real device API versions, permissions? And what you did after get images in filePathCallback?

Check that you have internet permission if the image is in online, and readable permission if the image is stored in your device and then try again after giving this two permissions
In your manifest.xml
